# Pygame runs slower after splitting the game into different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pygame, game-development

I've written a simple game in pygame. It used to be all in one file, but I decided to keep it clean, so I separated the code into different scripts. After doing so, the game runs much slower than before. I believe the lag is caused by refering to imported variables and functions every frame, but yet still don't know how to fix the issue. Here's the code, hope you can help:

**main.py**

```
import pygame
import player
import window

def main():
    pygame.init()

    running = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        window.refresh()
        player.run()

        clock.tick(window.FPS)
        print(clock.get_fps())
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**player.py**

```
import pygame
from math import sqrt
from window import WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIN
from classes import *

player = Obj(50, 50, 50, 10)

def normalize(x, y):
    if x != 0 and y != 0:
        return (x / sqrt(2), y / sqrt(2))
    return (x, y)


def movement(obj: Obj):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    startx = obj.x
    starty = obj.y

    x = 0
    y = 0

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= obj.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += obj.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= obj.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += obj.vel

    pos = normalize(x, y)

    obj.x += pos[0]
    obj.y += pos[1]

    speed = abs(sqrt((obj.x - startx) ** 2 + (obj.y - starty) ** 2))
    # print(speed)


def on_track(obj: Obj):
    if obj.x >= WIDTH - obj.size:
        obj.x = WIDTH - obj.size
    if obj.x <= 0:
        obj.x = 0
    if obj.y >= HEIGHT - obj.size:
        obj.y = HEIGHT - obj.size
    if obj.y <= 0:
        obj.y = 0


def run():
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (Color.black), (player.x, player.y, player.size, player.size))
    movement(player)
    on_track(player)
    pygame.display.update()
```

**window.py**

```
from classes import *
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
FPS = 60


def refresh():
    WIN.fill(Color.white)
```

**classes.py**

```
class Color(): 
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    blue = (0, 0, 255)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    green = (0, 255, 0)


class Obj():
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, vel):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.vel = vel
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You call `pygame.display.update` twice (in `player.run` and `main.main`) but otherwise I don't see any issue and your code runs smoothly on my computer. I also put everything in the same file and don't notice any difference. Have you tried to [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) the code?

Comment: Oh my god, that indeed was an issue. Also, I should've clarified that I am a Mac user, since it's not rare when the OS ends up being a problem. Perhaps Windows handles repeated `display.update`'s in another way, and this is why it ran smoothly on your PC. Anyways, could you please duplicate the comment in the answer section as it so happened that it turned out to be a solution

Comment: Done. OK, good to know.  I run a Linux Debian. Not tested on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `pygame.display.update` twice (in `player.run` and `main.main`).
Removing it from `player.run` solves the problem.